# WP Alchemy Meta Box function Causing wp-admin to run incredibly slow after database transfer

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function, import

I recently changed directories on my wordpress site. I exported my database, searched and replaced the old URL for the new URL and re-imported. The front-end of the site works fine but the backend on any page takes almost 15 seconds to load.

Removing my wp alchemy function from functions.php fixes the issue, but it wasn't causing any issues prior to the database transfer. I have no idea what I did wrong in transferring the database.

```
// VIDEOS META BOX 
define('THEMEASSETS', STYLESHEETPATH . '/assets/functions');

include_once 'assets/functions/MetaBox.php';
if (is_admin()) wp_enqueue_style('custom_meta_css', 'wp-content/themes/re/assets/css/meta.css');

$video_metabox = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_videoMeta',
    'title' => 'Videos',    
    'types' => array('characters','homepage','page'),
    'template' => THEMEASSETS . '/video_meta.php'
));
```

If anyone has any insight into this issue, please let me know. I can buy you a beer or even dinner if you can help me get this resolved-- I'm trying to launch a site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are the paths correct? you may also consider using the following:

```
// include css to help style our custom meta boxes
add_action( 'init', 'my_metabox_styles' );

function my_metabox_styles()
{
    if ( is_admin() )
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_meta_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/meta.css' );
    }
}
```